# python selenium - get (ctrl-u) equivalent page_source

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the **ctrl-u** equivalent of `browser.page_source` for comparative purposes.

is this possible with `browser.execute_script` or another method?

I've tried various methods like `browser.get(view-source:https://www.example.com)` but haven't seen a solution.

Answer (score 1):

if I'm not wrong you want to compare original html `ctrl+U` and rendered html `browser.page_source`, for that you can use `requests`

```
import requests

originalHTML = requests.get('http://...').text
print(originalHTML)
```

or you can create another tab for `view-source:`

```
url = 'https://..../'
browser.get(url)
renderedHTML = browser.page_source

# open blank page because JS cannot open special URL like `view-source:`
browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank')")
# switch to tab 2
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])
browser.get("view-source:" + url)
originalHTML = originalHTML = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body').text

# switch to tab 1
#browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: `browser.get('view-source:https://www.example.com'); html = browser.page_source` …. does not return the (ctrl-u) text into the `html` variable ….. plus this need to happen on a button click which provides no address to append `view-source:` onto the beginning. I could extract the url after the button is clicked … and append `view-source:` then reload the url … but that would also require loading the same page twice

Comment: @Rhys , can you update your question with exact scenario and problem description?

Comment: All I can add is an example site for testing. The question in its simplest form is … put all ctrl-u text into a variable (without adding view-source: to the url)

Comment: here is the example site `https://www.blsst.co.nz/` …. one work around which may support your answer would be to physically call the ***ctrl+u*** shortcut thus opening a new tab without reloading the page. But I'm not sure how to do that. Then somehow copy the displayed html into a variable

Comment: Since this is a button click. I don't have target URL until button is clicked. After clicking the button I have the url …. but loading the url a second time increases traffic on the website, adding unnecessary stress on the website. Is this the best or only way to get the ***ctrl+u*** source?

Comment: @ewwink is there anyway to append `view-source:` onto `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button[0])` So the page does not need to be loaded twice?

Comment: see comment in the script answer `JS cannot open special URL like view-source:`

Comment: alternatives are, **1.** `ActionChains.context_click().perform()` but I've found no way to access the right click menu. **2.** `.send_keys` for shortcut `ctrl+u` … but shortcuts do not work in python apparently. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Its works fine for me , I guess it's the problem with the quotes,

```
browser.get('https://www.example.com')
browser.page_source
```

You can also achieve the same using `browser.execute_script()`

```
browser.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one. It returns additional data at the end of the html and incorrect tabs, spacing and newlines

Comment: You get newlines and tabs because it returns a unicode. If newlines and tabs are your only problem you can just write a helper function to remove them. you can use split() or strip() accordingly.

Comment: that's good to keep in mind. if you check the `documentElement.outerHTML` vs the ***ctrl+u*** source, at the bottom of the page you'll see there is additional code. for the above example. I'm guessing there are plenty more examples